# How to create a filter on the ForeignKey Field in a Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `Detail` Model which has a ForeignKey of the default `User` Model of Django. It works fine, but I want the ForeignKey to be attached to only those users which are neither staff nor superuser.

My `Detail` model is below:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(20)], verbose_name="Skype Session Attendances (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the numbers of skype sessions of this subject, the student attended out of 20.")
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(40)], verbose_name="Internal Course Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total internal course marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 40.")
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(25)], verbose_name="Programming Lab Activities (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total numbers of programming lab activities of this subject, the student participated in, out of 25.")
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(45)], verbose_name="Mid_Term Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total mid-term marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 45.")
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(90)], verbose_name="Final_Term Marks (of this subject, in numbers)", help_text="Enter the total final-term marks of this subject, the student obtained out of 90.")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-{self.subject}'
```

I want something like below:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, filter(not user.is_superuser, not user.is_staff))
```

But it does not work, anyone know how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Create either an intermediate model, or put in this restriction when creating a `Detail` instance. Or try adding a custom validator for your ForeignKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using "limit_choices_to" argument in the ForeignKey. 
You can read more about it in the below link. 
https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.ForeignKey

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple solutions, One of them is.

```
def is_superuser(user):
    return user.is_superuser  ## customize as needed
```

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, validators=[is_superuser])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but answer of @ms394 was more accurate and worked for me as well.

Comment: Both work like a charm, as I told you, there're multiple solutions and I just mentioned one of them :)